# Files uploaded with multer disappears when the heroku server restarts

Tags: node.js, heroku, multer

I am using `multer` in `node.js` to upload files (that are coming from a client project based on Angular) to my Heroku server. Everything works fine, but when the Heroku server restarts or goes down all the uploaded files disappears, the `URL hits` returns '`Not Found`'.

This is my code to upload files :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var multer = require('multer');
var pool = require('./dbconnection');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/app/public/images/postImages/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+'.jpg')
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


router.post('/postImages', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {

var userId              = req.body.userId;
var postTitle           = req.body.postTitle;
var postDesc            = req.body.postDesc;
var postLat             = req.body.postLat;
var postLng             = req.body.postLng;
var postMediaType       = req.body.postMediaType;
var postMediaFileName   = req.file.filename;
var postMediaFilePath   = req.file.destination;
var postMediaFileURL    = req.file.path;
postMediaFileURL        = postMediaFileURL.substring(postMediaFileURL.indexOf('images/'), postMediaFileURL.length);

var inserts = [postTitle, postDesc, postLat, postLng, postMediaType, postMediaFileName, postMediaFilePath, postMediaFileURL, userId];
var sql = "INSERT INTO posts (postTitle, postDesc, postLat, postLng, postMediaType, postMediaFileName, postMediaFilePath, postMediaFileURL, userId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
console.log(sql);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results) {
        connection.release();
        res.json(results);
        if(error) throw error;
    });
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Tell me what am I missing or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks, i will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your question, it's heroku. after the application restarts only the deployed files will stay on the server.

I suggest using a remote storage, I recommend 'cloudinary' as a free solution for media storage.

But if you want to stick with heroku as a storage there is always the option to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you so much, this recommendation of yours is going to be very helpful for me.